# How get friends Check Ins since a date?

Tags: facebook-graph-api

So i'm trying to get friends check ins form a specific date up to "now"
Like so:

```
   search?type=checkin&since=1343613333633
```

(1343613333633 = 30 Jul 2012 01:55:33 GMT)

And I always get {"data":[]}

with out the "since" param i some check ins (all of them after that date)

i get the same results both on graph api explorer and from Android Facebook SDK (not sure if this is important)

How do i fix this?


Thx in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can easily use [FQL](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/fql/checkin/) to do it:

```
SELECT coords, tagged_uids, page_id, timestamp FROM checkin WHERE author_uid IN (SELECT uid2 FROM friend WHERE uid1 = me()) and timestamp > 1312971542
```

will give you the list of friend checkins of the current logged in user since *timestamp*. Be sure to have the friends_checkins permission when retrieving the access token.